Asking for proof check on an injective mapping exercise
Statement is simple: Given a linear map $T$ from some space $V$ of dimension $n$ into itself, prove that its matrix representation must have its columns as some basis of $F^{n, 1}$ and its rows as some basis of $F^{1, n}$.
This is quite tricky but a bit trivial. Let $\mathcal{M}(T) = A$ with an injective $T: V \rightarrow W$. Denote $v_1, ..., v_n$ as some basis of $V$ and $w_1, ..., w_n$ as some basis of $W$. Now, it is clear from the definition that
$$Tv_k = A_{1, k}w_1 + ... + A_{n, k}w_n\quad(1)$$
Suppose that there exists $a_1, ..., a_n$ such that
$$a_1Tv_1 + ... + a_nTv_n = 0\quad(2)$$
It then follows that
$$T(a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n) = 0 \Rightarrow a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n = 0 \Rightarrow a_1 = ... = a_n = 0$$
due to the injectivity of $T$ and the linear independence of $v_1, ..., v_n$.
Also, from $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$a_1(A_{1, 1}w_1 + ... + A_{n, 1}w_n) + ... + a_n(A_{1, n}w_1 + ... + A_{n, n}w_n) = 0$$
$$= (a_1A_{1, 1} + ... + a_nA_{1, n})w_1 + ... + (a_1A_{n, 1} + ... + a_nA_{n, n})w_n = 0$$
, which then follows that
$$a_1A_{1, 1} + ... + a_nA_{1, n} = 0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_1A_{n, 1} + ... + a_nA_{n, n} = 0$$
due to the basis $w_1, ..., w_n$. Or equivalently, the equation
$$a_1\begin{pmatrix}
 A_{1, 1} \\
 \vdots \\
 A_{n, 1}
\end{pmatrix} + ... + a_n\begin{pmatrix}
 A_{1, n} \\
 \vdots \\
 A_{n, n}
\end{pmatrix} = 0\quad(3)$$
It is not hard to prove that given $(1)$, the $a_1, ..., a_n$ satisfying $(3)$ must also satisfies $(2)$, which proves the set
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 A_{1, 1} \\
 \vdots \\
 A_{n, 1}
\end{pmatrix}, ..., \begin{pmatrix}
A_{1, n} \\
\vdots \\
A_{n, n}
\end{pmatrix}$$
linearly independent.
Furthermore, the set is linearly independent with length $n$ in $F^{n, 1}$ which implies that it must be some basis. Now, since the column and row rank are equal, it must hold that
$$dim(span((A_{1, 1}, ..., A_{1, n}), ..., (A_{n, 1}, ..., A_{n, n})))$$
must be the dimension of the span of the set
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 A_{1, 1} \\
 \vdots \\
 A_{n, 1}
\end{pmatrix}, ..., \begin{pmatrix}
 A_{1, n} \\
 \vdots \\
 A_{n, n}
\end{pmatrix}$$
, which is $dim(F^{n, 1}) = n$. Since its dimension is the same as its containing space $F^{1, n}$, it must be the whole space $F^{1, n}$. We have shown the list
$$(A_{1, 1}, ..., A_{1, n}), ..., (A_{n, 1}, ..., A_{n, n})$$
spans $F^{1, n}$ and since it has length $n$, it must also be some basis of $F^{1, n}$.


solution verification questions should be tagged solution-verification. 2. Posting a long proof and asking for it to be verified is off-topic and too broad (you are literally asking dozens of questions, one for each and every step). to be on topic, there must be a specific step that you are unsure about, and you must explicitly identify the step and ex0kicitly state what the doubt about it is.


While the overall logic is correct, there several inconguities in your post. The result you show does not require $T$ should map $V$ to itself. Indeed, you immediately switch to $T: V\to W$ instead. But you still unnecessarily require $\dim W = \dim V$. You never state in the question itself that $T$ must be injective (it is in the title, but not in the question), though you do use that fact (necessarily - the result is false otherwise). And you cannot talk about $\mathcal{M}(T)$ until after you choose the bases ${v_i}, {w_i}$ defining that matrix representation.
